# jQuery / JavaScript Function Scope / Hoisting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two files containing JavaScript and jQuery functions. They are referenced on the page in this order:

```
<script src="js/kiosk-functions.js"></script>
<script src="js/kiosk-main-socket-handler.js"></script>
```

In kiosk-functions.js I had originally done this -

```
$(function() {
    // some JavaScript functions
    function isJSON(str) {
        try {
            JSON.parse(str);
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
     }
     // some jQuery code follows...
});
```

Then, in kiosk-main.js I had this -

```
$(function() {
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('message', function (data) {

        if(isJSON(data)) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
    // other JavaScript and jQuery code
});
```

This resulted in the following error -

> Uncaught ReferenceError: isJSON is not defined

Once I moved the `isJSON()` function out of the document ready handler in kiosk-functions.js then all was well, but left me puzzled. I read a number of the answers here on SO trying to understand what was going on, being under the impression that the function would be hoisted and available globally. I didn't find anything that demonstrated this example.

I'm sure that I am missing something simple here. Does the document ready handler (a function) keep the `isJSON()` function from being hoisted? Or is it a simple scope issue?

Comment: javascript is function scoped (not speaking about `let` statement). `isJSON` is defined under the ready handler scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not hoisting, but the scope of the function.

Basically in `kiosk-functions.js` you define a callback to `document.ready` and inside that callback you define the function `isJSON()`. The function is just known within that scope.

In the second file `kiosk-main.js` you try to use `isJSON()` as if it was defined either in that callback's scope or in the global scope. Both is not the case, hence the error.

In order to solve this, you could add some global namespace `myNamespace` and attach your function there:

```
$(function() {
    // some JavaScript functions
    function isJSON(str) {
        try {
            JSON.parse(str);
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
     }

  // init namespace
  window.myNamespace = window.myNamespace || {};

  // attach function
  window.myNamespace.isJSON = isJSON;
});
```

Then in the other file you can reference that global namespace to call your function:

```
$(function() {
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('message', function (data) {

        if(myNamespace.isJSON(data)) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
    // other JavaScript and jQuery code
});
```

---

**Edit**

As mentioned by @Alnitak in the comments: In the browser the global object is `window`. Changed code accordingly.

Comment: The OP mentioned jQuery - chances are he wants `window` rather than `global`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on using the namespace, I had not had an opportunity to make use of that but it looks like I can take advantage of it on this project.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Not anymore ,-) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`$(function(){})` is just a shorter version of    `$(document).ready(function(){});`

In the above function, `this` is `document` and for a function to be global, it needs to be in `window` context.

Hoisting **isn't** your problem, the **scope in which the function is declared**, is.

If it is used widely in the code and if it isn't part of some specific module or library you're building, then you can just declare the function in the global context or just make the function, the property of `window`, which makes it global.

If it is some library or module then you can attach it to it making it specific to only that library/module.

In short, use namespacing or make it global if you really use it lot many times and is a generic function.

Comment: So the hoisting does not occur in that case?

Comment: @JayBlanchard it occurs but hoisting function is regarding scope

Comment: Ah! That makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Variables and function definitions are only hoisted within the enclosing function scope, which in your case is the anonymous function that you've passed to `$()`.  In that respect, hoisting is making no difference - it's simply that the `isJSON` function is defined in a different scope.

You may wish to consider the module namespace pattern:

```
var NAMESPACE = NAMESPACE || {};

NAMESPACE.isJSON = function() {
    ...
};
```

where `NAMESPACE` is a single global variable that will contain all of your locally defined functions.

The `NAMESPACE || {}` is there to ensure that the `NAMESPACE` object isn't overwritten if it already exists.